# How to change session token/cookie format in cookie when navigates to other website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, cookies, wif

I have 2 web applications, one is ASP.NET MVC 5 + WIF hosted in IIS, another is a web service based on WCF and self-hosted. Both of them are under same domain (so there are no security issues to change cookie format) and referring to the same STS (in same security realm), so theoretically if one user already authenticated, he should be able to access other entities within same security realm without authentication. 
However, these 2 websites are using different session token format. For ASP.NET MVC 5 project, it uses WIF implemented standard security session token and serialized to cookie; for WCF web service, it uses its own token/cookie format.

Then we have a problem.

When user navigates from ASP.NET MVC website to WCF web service, because WCF web service cannot recognize WIF session token (FedAuth and FedAuth1), so it redirects user to STS and login again, that is not the biggest problem, the biggest problem is, after use logged in, and POST raw SAML2 token back to WCF web service, WCF web service creates its own format token and tries to set client cookie, it actually doesn't work, I guess maybe there are already FedAuth and FedAuth1 cookie in header so header cannot accommodate more tokens (4K limit?)? Having thought about this for a while, there are are several solutions come into my mind:

1. Unifying token format. I need to subclass SecurityTokenHandler (maybe also need to subclass CookieHandler), use the same token format that WCF service uses, so when jumps to WCF web service, it can recognize the session token. That needs to dig deep into FAM and SAM.
2. Force re-login. I can clear FedAuth and FedAuth1 cookies before navigates to WCF web service, it is acceptable that user needs to login again, this is a short term fix, but how can I capture this *navigation away* event and clear cookie? The only way I think I can do is before I change window.location.href, use jQuery.cookie to clear cookie, I am not sure if it is the correct way, this is my first question.
3. Adding a cookie translation layer between ASP.NET and WCF, use WIF session token in ASP.NET website, and when jumps to WCF web service, change the token format. But for this solution I don't know how to capture the jump action and how can I get raw SAML2 token? May be I can save it in WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenReceived event handler? But how to deal with multi tokens from multi users and multi sessions?

Are there other better suggestions?